# Range of __utma cookie id

Tags: cookies, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using __utma cookie information for some processing. What could be integer range of random id in __utma cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Google Analytics` generating the random id using the code

```
 Math.round(Math.random()*2147483647);
```

So the `cid(clientId)` in the _utma cookie is less than 2147483647 .